# how to insert a new node if a doubly linked list is empty or has existing node

Tags: c++, linked-list

What am I doing wrong here? I'm new to linked lists and would appreciate some insight.

I am trying to add a new node in an empty list, or add a new node at the beginning if a node exists:

```cpp
void insert(node* previous, int value){
    if(previous == nullptr){
        node* newNode = new node;
        newNode->next = nullptr;
        newNode->prev = nullptr;
        (*head) = newNode;
        (*tail) = newNode;
    }else{
        node* newNode = new node;
        newNode->next = (*head);
        newNode->prev = nullptr;
        (*head)->prev = newNode;
        (*head) = newNode;
    }
}

class dlist {
public:
    dlist() { }

    struct node {
        int value;
        node* next;
        node* prev;
    };

    node* head() const { return _head; }
    node* tail() const { return _tail; }

private:
    node* _head = nullptr;
    node* _tail = nullptr;
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248071/discussion-on-question-by-dman-how-to-insert-a-new-node-if-a-doubly-linked-list).

Answer (score 0):

There are these issues:

- The code refers to `head` and `tail`, but these are not defined. There are `_head` and `_tail` members which should be used. They are not pointer-pointers, but just pointers.
- The code uses `previous` only to test against `nullptr`, nothing more. This can never accomplish that the new node should be inserted after that `previous` node.
- The code assumes that if `previous` is `nullptr` that the list is currently empty, but that is not the meaning of `previous`. `previous` is a reference to the node *after* which a new node must be inserted. This tells us nothing about the list being empty or not.
- The code assumes that the new node will always become the first in the list (as `newNode->prev` is always set to `nullptr`), but the goal is to make `newNode` the successor of `previous`, so that when `previous` is an existing node, `newNode->prev` should point to that `previous` node.
- The `value` argument is never used. This value should be assigned to the new node's `value` member.

Here is a possible correction to your code, although we have no way to test it on whichever platform you are to submit it:

```
    void insert(node* previous, int value) {
        node* newNode = new node; // Always create a new node (no matter what the case is)
        newNode->value = value; // Assign the argument as value
        newNode->prev = previous; // previous is always going to be the predecessor
        if (previous == nullptr) {  // newNode becomes the first node of the list
            newNode->next = _head;
            _head = newNode; // Set it is the new head
        } else { // newNode must come after previous
            newNode->next = previous->next;
            previous->next = newNode; // Set the reverse link
        }
        // If there is a node after the new node, it should have a backreference to it
        if (newNode->next != nullptr) {
            newNode->next->prev = newNode;
        }
        if (_tail == previous) { // Update tail 
            _tail = newNode;
        }
    }
```

Comment: ok i updated my post with what you wrote but i changed the "prev" parameter to "previous" to make it less confusing, does it look correct? also thanks for the comments it really helps understand whats going on

Comment: I rolled back your edit. It is not right to feed my code back into your question, as now my answer looks stupid. Renaming a parameter is certainly not a problem, but as your original question had `prev`, I did not change that. It is not essential.

Comment: oh okay sorry about that, but if i were to change the parameter name to "previous" would i have to change anything in that code you provided? i noticed on the provided hpp file on this assignment,  the provided parameter is "previous" and not prev, mistake on my part

Comment: I updated my answer to use `previous`, but it makes no difference in the functioning of the code.

Comment: ok that clarifies alot, thanks so much